# how to insert value in dropdown dynamically using json ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, html-select

`JSON` Object:

```
[
    { 
        "C_CO": 0,
        "C_NAME1": "All- (BSPL)"
    },{
        "C_CO": 2,
        "C_NAME1": "Solutions Pvt Ltd"
    }
]
```

how to populate dropdown in below coding?

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data) {
```

hereafter I don't know how to populate a `select`? I want to set the `c_co` value as dropdown value and set the `C_NAME1` value as dropdown text.

Comment: Please better format your code

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your JSON has mis-matched `}`. Assuming that is just a typo, you simply need to loop over the response of the AJAX request contained in the `data` variable and create a new `option` element in the iteration. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var options = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        options.push($('<option />', { value: item.C_CO, text: item.C_NAME1 }));
    });
    $('select').append(options);
}
```

Comment: Check the console. There may be errors elsewhere in your code, or an issue with the request itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


       jsonList =' [{ 
            "C_CO": 0,
            "C_NAME1": "All- (BSPL)"
        },{
            "C_CO": 2,
            "C_NAME1": "Solutions Pvt Ltd"
        }
    }]';
          var listItems= "";
          for (var i = 0; i < jsonList.Table.length; i++){
            listItems+= "<option value='" + jsonList.Table[i].C_CO+ "'>" + jsonList.Table[i].C_NAME1+ "</option>";
          }
          $("#DLState").html(listItems);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `<option>` tags with the innerHTML property. For example if you have a dropdown with id `dd` and your json data is assigned to `jsonData` then:

```
var dd=document.getElementById('dd');
dd.innerHTML+='<option>'+jsonData[i].C_NAME1+'</option>';
```

will add the value to the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="dynamicDropdown"></select>

<script>
    $.ajax({
        url : "",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data)  // data should be an array that you have mentioned.
            data.map(function(c){
                $("#dynamicDropdown").append("<option value="+c.C_CO+">"+c.C_NAME1+"</option>");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```